# Why do people say to enable NSDebugEnabled YES, when NSDebug.h comments seem to say that is the default?

Tags: cocoa, debugging

as in the question, i am trying to understand using environmental variables correctly, and also harness their power, but i'm confused by what i am finding.

caveat: cocoa, and Xcode 3.2.6 here.

Comment quote is:

> Here is a table of the variables/values initialized from the
>   environment at startup.

**NSDebugEnabled**
the DEFAULT listed as "YES".

is this comment trying to convey that this is how it is setup if i don't change anything ?

perhaps, i have had too much coffee, but this is confusing.

can someone explain please ? thanks.

Comment: By default NSDebugEnabled is present in Xcode and app settings.

Comment: @rishi, are you saying NSDebugEnabled is being 'used' unless i set it to NO ?

Comment: if we have defined anything then NSDebugEnabled is NO, and will not be used. Once we set that yes in environment variable then only it will work.

Comment: @rishi, thank you. if you write this as an answer, i can mark it as answered, and you can get the rep. points

Comment: No, the default listed in the header is `NO`. The columns aren't aligned properly under their headers in the comment, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't defined anything then `NSDebugEnabled` is NO, and will not be used. Once we set that yes in environment variable then only it will work.